# Why doesn't a customized color work with tikzpeople?

Tags: color, tikzpeople

If I use `brown!50` to fill a node, it works.

If I use `pink` for Alice's skin in `tikzpeople`, it works.

But it I use `brown!50` for Alice's skin, it doesn't work. Why?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\colorlet{mybrown}{brown!50}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[alice, minimum size=3cm, skin=mybrown] (carla) {This doesn't work};
    \node[alice, minimum size=3cm, skin=pink, left = of carla] {This works}; 
    \node[fill=mybrown, above=of carla] {This works};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine. Try with green. But the skin has a lighter tone by default. Compare the skin pink with normal pink.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: It seems to be a shading/fading: Pursue the tone gradient from the hair to the lower 'face'

Comment: The code for the skin style  is `skin/.style=        {color=\tikzpeople@skin,top color=\tikzpeople@skin!70, bottom color=\tikzpeople@skin,shading angle=45},`, so it is shaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works. You can see it if you try with a more distinct color like e.g. green.

But the skin isn't colored uniformly. The code contains a shading:

```
skin/.style= {color=\tikzpeople@skin,
              top color=\tikzpeople@skin!70, 
              bottom color=\tikzpeople@skin,shading angle=45},
```

and so the color looks lighter than you expect.